# Decreasing positive function less than $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers

Is there a decreasing function $f$ defined on $(0,∞)$ such that $0<f(x)<x$?
I thought about it and couldn't come up with a conventional function. I was thinking that for all $x>0$ we can find (smallest) $n_x$ which satisfies $\frac{1}{n_x}<x$. If I can construct these $n_x$s such that $n_x>n_y$ whenever $x>y$ I will be done. But maybe I'm thinking too deep and the answer is much simpler than that.

Comment: @GCab ln(1+x) is not decreasing?

Comment: This seems impossible because to be decreasing the must start at the smallest possible values of teeny weeny $x$ and be some value that only gets smaller.  So the value of $f(x)$ must always be as small as teen weeny $x$ which can never be any bigger than the absolute smallest it can be. As $x>0$ can be as close to $0$ as we like $f(x)$ must be closer to zero than that so $f(x)$ can never be anything.  We just have to find a way to formally state that.  And for all $x,n; 0<\frac 1n< x$ we have $f(x)<f(\frac 1n)< \frac 1n$ and we can take $n\to \infty$ so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you require $f$ to satisfy $0 < f(x) < x$ for every $x \in \left( 0, \infty \right)$.
Then the answer is no. One way to see this is to note that for any fixed $x \in \left( 0, \infty \right)$ the estimate
$$ f(x) < f(n^{-1}) < n^{-1}$$
holds for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > x^{-1}$.
But letting $n \to \infty$ then shows that $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $t \in (0, \infty)$ such that $t < \min(f(1), 1)$. If such $f$ exists, we have $f(t) \geq f(1)>t $ since $f$ is decreasing. On the other hand, we have $0<f(t) < t $. Thus we have $$0<f(t)<t<f(1)\leq f(t)$$
which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

How could it be?

Let $x > 0$. what is $f(x)$?.  As the function is decreasing, then  for any $\epsilon; 0 < \epsilon < x$ we must have $f(x) \le f(\epsilon)$.  But your condition that $0 < f(x) < x$ for all $x$ means $f(\epsilon) < \epsilon$.

So for any $x$ we must have $f(x)\le f(\epsilon) < \epsilon$ for any positive $\epsilon$.  But your condition is that $f(x) > 0$ so that means $f(x) < f(x)$ itself.

(Note:  Is a well-known that if $a < \epsilon$ for any positive $\epsilon$ that $a \le 0$.  Because if $a > 0$ then $a < a$ itself.)